# Powershell Test-Path UNC returns false

Tags: powershell

I know there are already some threads on this, but i dont get it...

ive got a list of file locations from a sql and extract them:

```
$results = --SQL QUERY--
$result = $results | select Dateipfad, Pfad, Datei, etc...
$dateipfad = $result | select Dateipfad
$dateipfad
```

| Dateipfad |
| --- |
| \\fs-srv01\folder1\folder2\file1.pdf |
| \\fs-srv01\folder1\folder2\file2.pdf |
| \\fs-srv01\folder1\folder2\file3.pdf |
| \\fs-srv01\folder1\folder2\file4.pdf |

and when testing with **Test-Path -Path $Dateipfad** i get:

```
False
False
False
False
```

but when i use **Test-Path -Path '\\fs-srv01\folder1\folder2\file4.pdf'**
its always true

Comment: Please try to create a full [mcve] including how you assign the paths to `$Dateipfad` (not only for us but also for yourself to understand the problem you're facing)

Comment: [`$dateipfad = $result | select-object -ExpandProperty Dateipfad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

Answer (score 0):

alright i fixed it by using **Test-Path -Path ('filesystem::'+$_.dateipfad)**

and adding **filesystem::** to the path